# Do all entangled states violate some Bell inequality?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, bells-inequality

Suppose I have a multipartite pure entangled two-level system. Is it always possible to form a bell-inequality based on this state such that the observed correlations cannot be reproduced classically? Is there any straightforward way to form such inequalities?

Answer (score 1):

It is true if you restrict to pure states, but not for general states. There are (bipartite) entangled states which admit local hidden variable models.
The standard references on this are [*Werner's 1989 PRA*](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.40.4277) and [*Wiseman et al. 2007*](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0612147).

Werner's way of showing this is to explicitly construct a local hidden variable model for a state that is not separable.
They consider what are now called *Werner states*, which are bipartite states $W\in\mathrm D(\mathbb C^d\otimes\mathbb C^d)$ --- where $\mathrm D(\mathcal H)$ denotes the set of density matrices on the Hilbert space $\mathcal H$ --- such that $(U\otimes U)W(U^\dagger\otimes U^\dagger)=W$ for any unitary $U:\mathbb C^d\to \mathbb C^d$.
These can also be given a more explicit form, as
$$W_{p,n}=p\frac{\Pi_+}{\binom{n+1}{2}} + (1-p)\frac{\Pi_-}{\binom{n}{2}},$$
where $\Pi_\pm$ are the projections onto the $\pm1$ eigenspaces of the swap operator: $\mathrm{SWAP}|i,j\rangle=|j,i\rangle$:
$$\Pi_\pm\equiv\frac12(I \pm \mathrm{SWAP}).$$
The binomial coefficients are due to the dimensions of the symmetric and asymmetric subspaces on which these projectors operate. See [Watrous' book](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ewatrous/TQI/) for more details on this.

One can see that Werner states are entangled for $p\in[0,1/2)$, *e.g.* via PPT criterion, and also that they are separable for $p\ge1/2$ with another approach (again, discussed in Watrous' book). However, as Werner shows, local hidden variable models can be found also for $p\ge1/2$. I asked a question concerning the explicit construction on qc.SE [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/21523/55).

Another related post on qc.SE is [*What is an example of an entangled state whose correlations are describable with a local hidden variable model?*](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/17184/55).

Comment: So is there a way to form bell inequality for an arbitrary pure state?

Comment: @Dotman that's actually a good question. Brunner et al., in https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.2849, page 20, state that all pure entangled state violate the CHSH inequality, and attributes this result to *Gisin 1991* (https://doi.org/10.1016/0375-9601(91)90805-I) and *Home, Selleri 1991* (https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02811227). Unfortunately, I cannot seem to find an accessible copy of the former, and don't quite have the energy right now to find the statement in the 100 pages of the latter. I'll see if I can find an easy way to show this